# How to make Selenium wait until an element is present?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, predicate

I'm trying to make Selenium wait for an element that is dynamically added to the DOM after page load. I tried this:

```
fluentWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElement(By.id("elementId"));
```

In case it helps, here is `fluentWait`:

```
FluentWait fluentWait = new FluentWait<>(webDriver) {
    .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

But it throws a `NoSuchElementException`. It looks like `presenceOfElement` expects the element to be there, so this is flawed. This must be bread and butter to Selenium, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel... Is there an alternative, ideally without rolling my own `Predicate`?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to call `ignoring` with an exception to ignore while the `WebDriver` will wait.

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
        .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

See the documentation of [FluentWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) for more information. But beware that this condition is already implemented in [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html), so you should use:

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

[*Fewer versions of Selenium](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/):

```
withTimeout(long, TimeUnit) has become withTimeout(Duration)
pollingEvery(long, TimeUnit) has become pollingEvery(Duration)
```

So the code will look as such:

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> fluentWait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
        .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30)
        .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(200)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

A basic tutorial for waiting can be found [here](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/).

Comment: either it should be <WebDriver> or it should be <> if you are using java 8 <driver> would give you compilation error.

Comment: Its NOT implemented in ExpectedCondition....its in WebDriverWait.  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepTimeOut) {
        super(driver, clock, sleeper);
        this.withTimeout(timeOutInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.pollingEvery(sleepTimeOut, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        this.ignoring(NotFoundException.class);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

Answer (score 16):

Use:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
```

You can use this as some time before loading the whole page, the code gets executed and throws an error. The time is in seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Let me recommend you using [Selenide](http://selenide.org) library. 
It allows writing much more concise and readable tests. It can wait for presence of elements with much shorter syntax:

```
$("#elementId").shouldBe(visible);
```

Here is a sample project for testing Google search:
https://github.com/selenide-examples/google

Comment: No chance this is being ported to python?

Comment: It's ported to Python. See "Selene" python library.

Answer (score 0):

FluentWait throws a NoSuchElementException is case of the confusion

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
```

with

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

in

```
.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public WebElement fluientWaitforElement(WebElement element, int timoutSec, int pollingSec) {

    FluentWait<WebDriver> fWait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(timoutSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .pollingEvery(pollingSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, TimeoutException.class).ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        try {
            //fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='reportmanager-wrapper']/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li/span[3]/i[@data-original--title='We are processing through trillions of data events, this insight may take more than 15 minutes to complete.']")));
        fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
        fWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        System.out.println("Element Not found trying again - " + element.toString().substring(70));
        e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    return element;

    }
```