# How to locate a button defined within a list?

Tags: css, list, button, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a selenium script that automates a web-page. I need to click on a button which is defined within a list.

This is the image of my web UI - `New Account` is the button I am referring to

[image]

This is my XML code :

```
<div id="00B4E000000LQ2C_topNav" class="topNav primaryPalette">
  <div id="00B4E000000LQ2C_subNav" class="subNav">
    <div class="linkBar brandSecondaryBrd">
      <div id="00B4E000000LQ2C_listButtons" class="listButtons">
        <ul class="piped">
          <li>
            <input class="btn" type="button" title="New Account"       onclick="navigateToUrl('/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=Account&ekp=001&retURL=%2F001%3Ffcf%3D00B4E000000LQ2C%26isdtp%3Dnv%26nonce%3Df8007ad94993912b7ff4149193a6096ccfed4ebb1454e0b9b310ad14b61de71d%26sfdcIFrameOrigin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fcs83.salesforce.com&save_new_url=%2F001%2Fe%3FretURL%3D%252F001%253Ffcf%253D00B4E000000LQ2C%2526isdtp%253Dnv%2526nonce%253Df8007ad94993912b7ff4149193a6096ccfed4ebb1454e0b9b310ad14b61de71d%2526sfdcIFrameOrigin%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fcs83.salesforce.com&isdtp=vw','LIST_VIEW','new');" name="new" value="New Account"/>
          </li>
          <li class="lastItem">
        </ul>
```

I used:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00B4E000000LQ2C_listButtons']/ul/li[1]/input")).click();
```

(Xpath was given by the firebug) but it gives me an error stating

> unable to locate elements

Please help me script / locate this button.

Comment: why not giving it a semantic class name, and select via that? `class="js-new-account-button"` and in the JS do something like `element(by.css('.js-new-account-button')).click();`

Comment: you have strange 1 after li. is it in the real code?

Comment: @splash58 press the 1, it's a link to an image. SO probably parsed it that way because of the brackets.

Comment: very unexpected. but it is so :)

Comment: ur problem is solved?

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed! It would be valuable to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try like below

```
// first way 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='new']")).click();
// second way 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn']")).click();
// basically you can use various attributes of input tag with button inside the xpath to click
```

Update working with i frame

```
// A short way to identify how many iframe's are present on a web page

List<WebElement> numberOfFrames= driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
System.out.println("Total Number of iframes present are : " +numberOfFrames.size());
for(int i=0;i<numberOfFrames.size();i++){
    // here u can identify iframes with any of its attribute vale say name,title or which is most suitable.
    System.out.println("Name of the i-frames : " + numberOfFrames.get(i).getAttribute("name"));
}

// Back to your question - button lies inside iframe hence
// key here is before clicking you have to switch to the frame first

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("frame name")));
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . I tried . Still the same error Unable to locate the element

Comment: Strange .are you getting unable to locate element error in the console ? if yes are you sure the button which you want to click is not inside any i-frame.also to add have you managed synchronization of the code if not please use link provided by @ alecxe

Comment: Yes, I am getting error in the console. I guess the button I want to click is inside i-frame. Can you see the image attached ? left most portion near xpath mentions about i-frame. Can you please help me with this .

Comment: Hi Rajnish, Yes- Button is inside an iframe. It mentions iframe#ext-comp-1005 input[name="new"] . How do i add synchronisation for the code ? Didn't find the link which @alecxe provided

Comment: hi i have updated my answer please have a look at it it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Rajnish for your help :)

Comment: @ raj N ish Ku M ar -   It gives me this error - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Comand . I ahve increased the time duration but I still find the same error . Could you tell me how do I get rid of this , Please.

Comment: plz try this it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use XPaths generated by the Firebug and check the element's parents along the way. We can do better, you can write a more reliable and a simpler way to locate the element:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("new"));
```

or:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name=new]"));
```

or:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='New Account']"));
```

---

Note that the XPath expression you have looks valid. You may be experiencing a timing issue and would need to wait for the element presence, visibility or clickability, see: [How to wait until an element is present in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present).

And, if the button is inside the `iframe`, you need to switch to its context and only then search the button:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ext-comp-1005");
```

Comment: You mean `('input[name="New Account"]')`. The `value` obviously changes as the user enters it.

Comment: @Narxx well, I bet the user would not be able to change the button's value :)

Comment: Thanks for ur reply . I tried . Still the same error Unable to locate the element

Comment: @Chaitanya have you tried adding a wait with `WebDriverWait`? Also, check if this element is inside an iframe or not. Thanks.

Comment: Hi alecxe,  The button is inside the i-frame , it mentions  - iframe#ext-comp-1005 . How do I proceed with this ?

Comment: @Alecxe - It worked ! Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @alecxe : It gives me this error - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with Comand . I ahve increased the time duration but I still find the same error . Could you tell me how do I get rid of this , Please.