# Selenium - FireFox/Marionette driver is too fast to control

Tags: selenium, firefox, wait, geckodriver, firefox-marionette

After updating to the Firefox to version 52, i had to update gecko driver to v17. But all my previous scripts fail in Firefox, becase it is too fast and not wating for element on the page to load.

I am now forced to add Thread.sleep wait for each click. Is there any solution you guys can help me with?

Works in Chrome better, but need both to be working the same.

I run testNg and the exception i get is: Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

I fixed it by insterting Thread.sleep which is not recommended but this is the only thing that works. Fluent wait didnot work or me

1505314327534   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:42753
1505314328131   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\User\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.NX5A3KOOQr
1505314328136   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe with args []
1505314328150   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:65331
1505314331570   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 65331

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until an element is present in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium)

Comment: @JeffC - Probably, you didn't understand the question. User is saying, the scripts used to run in previous version but not in updated version because it is too fast and asking for the better solution. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Kapil OP said that they are having to add sleeps before each click. The better way to handle that is use `WebDriverWait` which is referenced in the duplicate question. I don't see anything unique here that requires a solution other than using proper waits. If the driver/browser is fast, you want the script to be as fast as possible. Sleeps slow everything down and are not a best practice.

Answer (score 1):

One of the objective of Test Automation is to reduce the `Test Execution` time. So it should make us glad if the driver of Firefox i.e. `geckodriver` which uses `Marionette` acts faster. Now your question must be how to synchronize the `geckodriver` with the real-time `Mozilla Firefox Browser`.

1. In your question you mentioned about adding `Thread.sleep(n)`. Slowing down inducing `Thread.sleep(n)` is not a part of Best Programming practices. It degrades the performance. So lets look at the other available options.
2. Next you mentioned about `not waiting for element on the page to load`. This is a common issue faced while we use `WebDriver`. The simplest way to address this is to induce `ImplicitWait`. In short, by introducing `ImplicitWait` the driver will poll the `HTML DOM` for the configured amount of time looking out for the element or elements. By that time the element or elements for which you had been looking for may be available in the `HTML DOM`. An example of `ImplicitWait` is as follows:

   - **Python**:

     ```
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)
     ```
   - **Java**:

     ```
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     ```

You can find the [official documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) here and also find a [detailed **`stackoverflow discussion`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706) here.

3. `ImplicitWait` can slow down your Test Execution quite drastically. So in that case **`ExplicitWait`** comes to our rescue. In short, **`ExplicitWait`** is a code block you define, configure and implement for the WebDriver instance to wait for a certain condition to be met before proceeding for the next line of code. An example of **`ExplicitWait`** is as follows:

   - **Python**:

     ```
     password = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "your_xpath")))
     password.send_keys("your_password")
     ```
   - **Java**:

     ```
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
     WebElement password = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("your_xpath")));
     password.sendKeys("your_password");
     ```

You can find the [official documentation here](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) and also find a [detailed **`stackoverflow discussion`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) here.

Answer (score 0):

Works in Chrome better, but need both to be working the same.

I run testNg and the exception i get is: Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

I fixed it by insterting Thread.sleep which is not recommended but this is the only thing that works. Fluent wait didnot work or me