# I'm trying to get page source code using Selenium, but I got empty page

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get page source code using Selenium, the code is general SOP. it worked out for Baidu.com and example.com. but when it comes to the URL i actually need,I got empty page.and the source code show nothing but empty tags like the following code. is there anything I missing?

I tried to add up some more params of options, but it doesn't seem helpful

WebDriver driver;

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\applications\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver_win32 (2)//chromedriver.exe");

    // 实例化一个WebDriver的对象    作用：启动谷歌浏览器
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm");
    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("==========="+title+"==============");
    System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(pageSource));
```

I expect the parsed page source of the URL so that I can get the info I need. but I'm stuck in here.

Comment: what's the output? try to change the path and see if it throws any exceptions, in this way you will make sure that it's not because driver can't be found.

Comment: The page is not loading properly on executing the script

Comment: Use explicit wait instead of implicit.

Comment: get rid of the implicit wait

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could reproduce the issue with this website when using ChromeDriver. What I found is that there is a JS detecting that you are using ChromeDriver and blocks the request to the web page with 400 HTTP error code:

[image]

Now, Firefox is working as expected with the following code:

```
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://rd.huangpuqu.sh.cn/website/html/shprd/shprd_tpxw/List/list_0.htm");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
    String title = driver.getTitle();
    System.out.println("==========="+title+"==============");
    System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(pageSource));

    driver.quit();
```

I used just a sleep for 5 seconds which worked. The best practice is to wait for a specific element in your page, check this for reference - [How to wait until an element is present in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium)

> firefox browser version: 67.0.1 geckodriver 0.24.0 selenium version:
>   3.141.59

Comment: thanks for you headsup. and I tried to download Firefox and its WebDriver for Selenium, but it seems there's compatibilty problem, could u tell me which version are you using of these three.that'll be really helpful.@Adi Ohana

Comment: @user9786842 edited my answer with the versions i'm using

Comment: thank you for the info. I've changed these version as needed. but I get the error——`Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.` then,I've done a little search,lots of answers suggest that it's a compatibility issue.I guess I’ll downgrade the firefox to give it another try.

Comment: and, I hope this is not too ask.With `selenium version: 3.141.59`. Does this mean I should just add the following dependency into my pom.xml or this is lots of other I need to add?
`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>3.141.59</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: Yes only add the dependency

Comment: okay, any idea about `Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.`error?

Comment: what is the OS you are running? and how do you run your java program?

Comment: My OS is windows10 and I run the code with IDEA 2019.1.2

Comment: i suggest you try downgrading the firefox browser version to 61 and geckodriver to v 0.20.1

Comment: BTW  my firefox's version is 67.0.2, this is I got when I download firefox from official site. it's a minor difference, I don't think there'll be much difference.

Answer (score 0):

first for all, it's for sure a compability problem. it is mainly because of selenium-it's been through lots of development,therefore, tons of problems about version compatibility.
Here is how I fianlly deal with this.

I chose Firefox browser to drive, the version is `67.0(64 bit)`.Cos Chrome will response with a blank result as @Adi Ohana mentioned. 
and I use Selenium with the version of 3.X.
to use Selenium 3.X,I add the following code in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version> <!-- this version context matters -->
        </dependency>
```

note this, it's `<artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>` you need add into your pom.xml.otherwise,you may get some unexpected error.

with these done, you need a proper driver.the driver for firefox named geckodriver.I use v0.24.0 version,it's a .exe file ranther than .jar so that you can specify it by java code in your programming like this:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","E:\\applications\\GeckoDriver-v0.24.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"); // 0.24.0 the 2nd param is the location of geckodriver.exe in your local computer
```

then, send a request for the URL.and since the body content is loaded by another AJAX request. you need wait a couple of second for Selenium to doing that.

```
Thread.sleep(5000); // this is the easyest way, may not the best though.
```

Conclusion:I get the original source code as I expected,but I do not tackle why googleDriver can not work as expected.I may leave this for a further digging.

Sum things up:
Firefox 67.0
geckodriver v0.24.0 [sepecfied by java-code]
Selenium 3.X [add by xml-code]

thanks for all you guys, it's been really helpful. like this community

PS:I'm new to use stackoverflow.still learning the ropes...