# How to fix NoSuchElementException Python error on clicking on webpage button?

Tags: python, css, selenium, webdriver, frame

Basically I need to click on a button, which is inside a frame on a webpage. I have tried:

1) Switching to frame, which works fine, doesn't return any errors:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#iframe'))
```

3) Adding time delay of 20 seconds, which doesn't change the result as it just times out in the end:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "dx-button"))).click()
```

I believe the CSS element's name is correct as I have copied it using Developer Mode -> Copy Selector.

**Is there anything else that I can do in order for selenium to find this CSS element?**

Error before adding time delay:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"dx-button"}
```

Error after adding time delay:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait until an element is present in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium)

Comment: Update your question with the relevant HTML.

Comment: Your wait is fine... I'm guessing your locator is off somehow but we need the HTML to be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

May be check if the switched iframe is the accurate one that has the button.

If that's correct, Can you try the same line with XPATH locators?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'button')]"))).click()
```