# How do I make send keys in Selenium work?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get('https://outlook.office.com/mail/')

driver.implicitly_wait(7)
login = driver.find_element_by_name("loginfmt")
login.send_keys("emailhere")
login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

password = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd")
password.send_keys("passwordhere")
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

It perfectly inputs the email and takes me to the password input screen, but at that point, it does not send the keys for the password. Any ideas on what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what may be causing your problem, but this question might help you: [How to wait until an element is present in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explicit wait is needed here. refer [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), so code will be like

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

password = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "passwd"))
    )

password.send_keys("passwordhere")
```

additional reference at: [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with below **code**, which is **maximizing the screen**, and then using `Name attribute` with `Explicit waits`, it is working fine.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://outlook.office.com/mail/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

login_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "loginfmt")))
login_btn.send_keys("some name")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[value='Next']"))).click()

password_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "passwd")))
password_btn.send_keys("Your password")
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```