# Eclipse-Selenium-Alternative to Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, selenium

I am relatively new to the Test Automation and in particular to the Selenium.
I am using Selenium Web-driver, Eclipse.
One of the biggest problems I am experiencing is that our scripts are crashing due to the Internet speed or server performance.
I currently use `Thread.sleep()` to solve the problem.
However it is not a secret that `Thread.sleep()` enforces waiting time till the timer is completed.
I tried to find an optimised solution in example for the script below.
Having  looked through the posts on Stackoverflow I found solution which is provided below in the `for(`) loop.
It was suggested to use:

```
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button_Sign).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("complete");
```

to ensure that action (click on the button) is completed, and if not, so to wait a little bit and to try again during the next iteration.
In my case below there would be 6 attempts as per loop.
However the code brings up an error:

> "Failure: Cannot invoke "Object.toString()" because the return value
> of "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor.executeScript(String,
> Object[])" is null"

The code is:

```
  public void SignSupportFormOnOrder() throws InterruptedException {
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)GlobalVariables._browser.currentDriver;
        ExplicitWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Order_SignSupportingForms));
        actions.moveToElement(Order_SignSupportingForms).click().perform();
        
        //Code working but using Thread.sleep():
        //Thread.sleep(10000); //Need to look for an alternative solution
        //jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button_Sign);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        
        //try as alternative to Thread.sleep(...):
        
        for(int i=0; i < 5; i++){   
            if(jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button_Sign).toString().equalsIgnoreCase("complete"))
                break;
            else
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

        //Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
```

Can somebody kindly give me a suggestion what I am doing wrong and how it would be possible to overcome using `Thread.sleep();`

Comment: [How to wait until an element is present in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20903328/1518100)

Comment: I there some other, more clean identification for the success of click on `button_Sign` element? Can you wait for some element appearance of disappearance instead of `toString().equalsIgnoreCase("complete")`? Why don't you use a regular selenium `.click()` or even actions click methods there?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, I used "button_Sign.click();" as you suggested.  It used to work, but at some point started to generate an error, so, I suggested an alternative solution:  "jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button_Sign)"

Comment: You didn't answer my first and main question: what is the indication of `button_Sign` element click success? That the click is worked or not? Some UI changes? Also please tag me so I could know you answered me.

Comment: @Prophet , Hello, thank you for the prompt answer again., button_Sign element click success:   It's a window that pops up to confirm that the user wants to complete the action.  When button Sign is clicked the pop is disappearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since clicking the `button_Sign` is closing some pop-up we can do some code like the following.

```java
public boolean clickVisibleDisappearsLoop(String xpath1, String xpath2){
    waitForElementToBeVisible(xpath1);
    int counter = 0;
    while (counter<10) {
        try {
            clickOnElement(xpath1);
            waitForElementToDisappear(xpath2,4);
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            wait(400);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Methods I have used here are:

```java
public void wait(int delay) {
    Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

public boolean waitForElementToDisappear(String xpath){
    try {
        wait.until((ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(By.xpath(xpath))));
        return true;
    }catch (Throwable t){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here you can pass the XPath locator of `button_Sign` element as `xpath1` and the XPath locator of pop-up that should close by clicking on `button_Sign` as `xpath2`.
Also, accordingly to Java conventions you should name the `button_Sign` as `buttonSign`. I would suggest naming it as `signBtn` or `signButton`.
Also, you dont have to return Booleans here, so you can simplify these methods making them `void`.

Comment: I'm happy I could help, you are welcome. As about naming - I understand

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, effort and explanations. Your code is working absolutely fine for me. Regarding button_Sign format (or lack of format to be more precise) I completely agree. But it was not me who suggested this name I just continue to maintain the old code.  Your help was really invaluable.  Thank you again.

Comment: You are right.  I upvoted. Is it only -1, 0, 1 points?

Comment: Upvote gives +10, accept +15, downvote -2

Comment: I see.  Thank you.  Will it be possible to ask you questions about Selenium in the future?

Comment: Sure. You can ask new questions and tag me in a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use Explicit wait with any element not appeared and mentioned needed time for it , for Ex:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("ElemnetNotExist")));
```

Comment: @Prophet Hello, I remember you kindly helped me before. I have a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72144555/eclipse-selenium-extract-the-value-from-the-table.  If you could have a look please. Of course if you have time. Thank you in advance.