# How to click on the button with Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to click the button first which I did and then the dropdown menu element which is **Tüm Soru Tipleri** automatically in Selenium Java.

This one is didn't work:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("select2-question_types-sq-result-xih0--1")).click();
```

Could you help?

HTML snapshot:

[image]

Element snapshot:

[image]

Comment: can you share the url of the page please @Sena

Comment: Here’s a few ideas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-wait-until-an-element-is-present-in-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a wait of 2 ms between button and drop-down.

Comment: I don't know how Thread.Sleep is not working i dont know why

Comment: @Prietesh you might want to consider describing how to wait in Selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Once you click and expand the [dropdown](/questions/tagged/dropdown) further to [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the desired `<li>` element with text as **Tüm Soru Tipleri** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and `text()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2-results']/ul[@id='select2-question_types-sq-results']//li[text()='Tüm Soru Tipleri']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `contains()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[@class='select2-results']/ul[@id='select2-question_types-sq-results']//li[contains(., 'Tüm Soru Tipleri')]"))).click();
  ```