Zooming on a leaflet map using Selenium
I am using selenium to interact with a web page that is using a fixed leaflet map on the right side of the page.
this is my code
try:

    random_sleep(1, 3)
    if not modal_checked:
    try:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    close_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button.popup__close[aria-label="Close popup"]')
                    
                    if close_button.is_displayed():
                        close_button.click()
                        print("Closed the modal popup.")
                except NoSuchElementException:
                    print("No modal popup found.")
            if zoom == False:
                print('looking for zoom')
                zoom_button =  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                     EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.page-link[aria-label="Zoom in"]'))
                )
                print('zoom button found')
                zoom_button.click()
                zoom = True
            page_source = driver

for some reason the script never find the button.. so I cannot click on it
I guess maybe because it is an external library .. but I do not know then how to interact with it

Maybe is because these buttons are generated dynamically and you should wait for the button to render. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20903231/how-to-make-selenium-wait-until-an-element-is-present
